# Combine dynamic API requests in RxJava Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I want to  loop multiple API requests  after response of one API and on complete of all requests I have to perform action.

First  API Response(getModels) =

```
 {
    "message":{
      "models":[
        {
          "equipno":"000000000001027019",
        
        },
        {
          "equipno":"000000000001027020",
        
        },
        {
          "equipno":"000000000001027021",
        
        },
        {
          "equipno":"FL3-PINRO-0001/011",
          
        }
]
}
}
```

Then I have to call second API in loop for all equipno received in first API response .

Second API response(getPrediction) -

```
{"body":{
    "status":"success",
    "message":{
      "equipno":"000000000001027019",
      "predictions":[
        {
          "date":"2020-09-01",
          "maintenance":true,
          "accuracy":13.07
        }
      ],
      "elapsed":0.03
    }
}
}
```

I tried to do using following Rx java code but its not working.

```
 val predictiveMaintenanceServiceCall = PredictiveMaintenanceServiceCall(context)
        val data = predictiveMaintenanceServiceCall.getModels(this).map { it.predictionMessage?.models?.map { it1 -> it1?.equipno } }


        data.map { items ->
            items.map { item ->
                predictiveMaintenanceServiceCall.getPrediction(item, dateFormatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().time))
            }
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ it ->
                Log.i("v ", "loadAlertsList zip ${it.size}")
                Observable.zip(it, Arrays::asList)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({ it ->
                        for (i in it as List<PredictionModel>)
                            Log.i("v ", "loadAlertsList ${i.message?.equipno}")

                    }, {
                        Log.i("v ", "loadAlertsList ${it}")
                    })

            },
                {

                })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if API is in your control then I suggest you update `getPrediction` API to except a list of `equipno`, so that you can call the API once and avoid all the unnesseary API calls.

As for how to do it currently, I suggest that instead of using RX you look into kotlin coroutines. your problem can be solved by following below steps.

### Make your retrofit functions suspendable

Retrofit 2.6.0 and above support suspend function, so all you have to do is to mark your `getPrediction` and `getModel` with suspend modifier as

```
suspend fun getModel(): List<Model>
suspend fun getPredication(equipno: String): List<Predication>
```

### Launch a coroutine to call API's (ideally this should be done in ViewModel)

```
private fun callAPI() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val models = getModels()
    models.forEach {
        val predication = getPrediction(it.equipno)
        // Do something with predication
    }
}
```